# Karate - How to call a function in a loop?

Tags: loops, karate

How to call my login function in a loop?

```
Feature: Validate correct user login
    Background:
        * call read('classpath:cleanup.feature')
        * def login = call read('classpath:account/init/init.user.feature')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Refer to the documentation on [data-driven features](https://github.com/intuit/karate#data-driven-features). So if you have a JSON array, you can do something like this:

```
* def users = [{ username: 'foo1', password: 'bar1' }, { username: 'foo2', password: 'bar2' }]
* def login = call read('classpath:account/init/init-user.feature') users
```

**edit**: since the question was not clear, adding a comment and one more example:

And inside `init-user.feature` you can just do `* print __arg`

Here is a an alternate way to iterate over a JSON array using a plain JavaScript function:

```
* def users = [{ username: 'foo1', password: 'bar1' }, { username: 'foo2', password: 'bar2' }]
* def fun = function(array){ for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) karate.log(array[i]) }
* call fun users
```

Comment: It's not what I'm asking, I want to know how to loop through a list for example printing each object inside users

Comment: @HomayounBehzadian ok.